# Javascript running and DOM loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

The following code is part of a .php file. Another php file ribbon.php, returns data via ajax call using json format. Whenever I run this code, everything is ok. However, **results_ribbon** actually does not exist in this certain point of code. Of course since ajax calls are asynchronous, code does not wait for ajax to be finished and continues with DOM loading that follows. By the time function **callit** arrives to event queue, **results_ribbon** is already present, so no problem.

```
...   
 <script type="text/javascript">  
          $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url:"ribbon.php",
            success: function callit(data) {
                if (data === "nothing")          
                   return;
                $("#results_ribbon").text(data); 
            }   
          });
</script>       
...
<div id="results_ribbon"></div>
 ...
```

However, as to deeply understand how this works I've changed the above code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
              $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url:"ribbon.php",
                success: function callit(data) {
                    if (data === "nothing")          
                       return;
                    $("#results_ribbon").text(data); 
                }   
              });
    var ms = 5000 + new Date().getTime();
       while (new Date() < ms)
         {}
    </script>
```

With that I gave time to ajax call to be finished and I thought that the event loop would give precedence to **callit** over DOM and as a  consequence **results_ribbon** 'd be unknown. However, my thought was correct only for Chrome; In Mozilla and IE everything continues to run like the first case! I cannot deduce something...

*Can someone explain to me or point some reading sources how exactly the Javascript code interferes with DOM loading when they coexist in the same file? Which has precedence and if it is possible for the browser to load both of them simultaneously in an parallel manner?*

Thank you

Comment: JS is single threaded, I think that all the process are queued until your while loop breaks (asynchronous code as well). You can check it by logging the time your while loop finishes and the time your ajax callback is actually called, it will be few ms after the while log.

Comment: Given that DOM rendering and JS code occupies a single thread,  it makes sense that the element would be available since the initial DOM load is a synchronous process that started before the asynchronous call was made. So we have the DOM starting to load, then we have your JS code with the AJAX and loop, then we continue the rest of the DOM rendering, then finally any async operations can run. I don't believe there's ever any special precedence given.